# Polybase to point to a file(s) locally on prem?

Tags: azure, orc, polybase

I have a unique situation where all my orc files are located on Azure on blob storage as compressed orc file. I need to load those files into on prem SQL DB. I can use polybase to download the data which I understand but it's taking extremely long time. I think network connectivity is the bottleneck here as poly base has to decompress those file, run map reduce job and retrieve the data via network into on prem SQL table. I don't have any other SQL box to try polybase scale out.

However I can download those orc files into local drive but I don't know how to write external data source to point local files. Microsoft doesn't have any documentation for it. Is it possible that external data source point to local orc file? I highly doubt it but just giving it a try.

Other solution is to decompress those orc file locally and load it but I don't know any tools to do that? Please suggest some tools.

Answer (score 0):

PolyBase doesn't support reading from local files location.